# Array Challenge Javascript

Tags: javascript

Saludos espero me ayuden, no logro encontrar mi error, lo que sucede es que estoy haciendo una funcion que resuelva el siguiente problema: Haga que la función ArrayChallenge( arr ) lea la matriz de enteros almacenada en arr que tendrá el siguiente formato: [K, r1, r2, r3, ...] donde K representa la cantidad de escritorios en un salón de clases y el resto de los enteros en la matriz estarán ordenados y representarán los escritorios que ya están ocupados. Todos los escritorios se organizarán en 2 columnas, donde el escritorio n.º 1 está arriba a la izquierda, el escritorio n.º 2 está arriba a la derecha, el escritorio n.º 3 está debajo del n.º 1, el escritorio n.º 4 está debajo del n.º 2, etc. debe devolver el número de maneras en que 2 estudiantes pueden sentarse uno al lado del otro. Esto significa que 1 estudiante está a la izquierda y 1 estudiante a la derecha, o 1 estudiante está directamente encima o debajo del otro estudiante.

Por ejemplo: si arr [12, 2, 6, 7, 11], hay un total de 6 formas de sentar a 2 nuevos estudiantes uno al lado del otro. Las combinaciones son: [1, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [8, 10], [9, 10], [10, 12]. Entonces, para esta entrada, su programa debería devolver 6 .

```
  function ArrayChallenge(arr) { 

   let highest = arr[0];
   let lowest = arr[0];
   let numberBetween = [];
   for(let i = 0;i<arr.lenght;i++){
    if(arr[i]>highest){
      highest=arr[i];
    }
    else {
      if(arr[i]<lowest){
      lowest=arr[i];
    }
    }
   }
   console.log('highest', highest);
   console.log('lowest', lowest);
   for(let j = lowest;j<=highest;j++){
    if(arr.indexOf(j)==-1){
      numberBetween.push(j);
    }
   }
   console.log('numberBetween', numberBetween);
   console.log('arr', arr);
   return numberBetween.length;

}
```

esta es la función que intenta resolver pero me sale 0;
gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Para que necesitas los valores mayor y menor?  Ademas estas contando la primera entrada como valor regular cuando es el numero de escritorios en el salon

Comment: muchas gracias como podría mejorar el codigo??

Comment: No tiene sentido que busques `highest` y `lowest`, el enunciado dice _"[...] el resto de los enteros en la matriz estarán ordenados y representarán los escritorios que ya están ocupados[...]"_. Mi consejo, dibuja los N bancos en 2 columnas, tacha los ya ocupados y empeza a marcar donde podrían entrar 2 nuevos alumnos en los banco libres. Hace varios casos, 12, 16, etc. Así vas a descubrir el patrón y te va a resultar más fácil pensar en como resolver tu problema.

Comment: Saludos no he podido resolverlo aún muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Pon en el título cuál es el problema _específico_ en cuestión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesante ejercicio...
Te digo como lo haría yo: 
Lo primero que debes hacer es sacar el primer valor del array, porque contiene el número de asientos, así lo aislamos de la lista de asientos ocupados.
Para ello utilizamos el método `array.shift()` que elimina el primer valor de un array y nos lo devuelve.
Ahora ya tenemos el array sólo con los asientos ocupados.
A continuación, vamos a crear un bucle con todos los posibles asientos y vamos a ir sumando las posibles combinaciones.
Si el asiento aparece en la lista, pasamos al siguiente, porque al estar ya ocupado, no va a sumar ninguna posibilidad, el resto comprobaremos asiento por asiento, si es impar si el asiento + 1 está libre (el de la derecha) y si es par el asiento - 1 (el de la izquierda). Debemos tener en cuenta que al ser parejas contiguas, el total de posibilidades estará duplicado porque, si por ejemplo detectase que la pareja (1 - 2) estuviese libre, también detectará la pareja (2 - 1).
También deberemos comprobar si el asiento + 2 (el de atrás) está libre.
Para todo esto, utilizaremos el método `array.include()` que nos devuelve true o false según si el valor que le pasamos existe en el array.

El código de tu función, quedaría así:

```
function ArrayChallenge(arr) {
    var asientos = arr.shift();
    var laterales = 0;
    var traseros = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= asientos; i++) {
        if (!arr.includes(i)) {
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                if (!arr.includes(i - 1)) {
                    laterales++;
                }
            } else {
                if (!arr.includes(i + 1)) {
                    laterales++;
                }
            }
            if (!arr.includes(i + 2) && (i <= asientos - 2)) {
                traseros++;
            }
        }
    }
    var posibilidades = (laterales / 2) + traseros;
    return (posibilidades);
}
```

Y aquí te lo dejo comentado y en un snippet para que puedas probarlo.

Un saludo.

```js
var arr = [12, 2, 6, 7, 11];
console.log(ArrayChallenge(arr));

function ArrayChallenge(arr) {
    // Guardamos el número de asientos y lo sacamos del array
    var asientos = arr.shift();
    // iniciamos posibles combinaciones de asientos
    var laterales = 0;
    var traseros = 0;
    // Recorremos todos los números de asientos posibles
    for (let i = 1; i <= asientos; i++) {
        // Si el asiento no aparece en la lista, está libre, por tanto comprobaremos su entorno
        if (!arr.includes(i)) {
            // Si el asiento es par, comprobamos si no está ocupado el asiento -1 (el de su izquierda)
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                if (!arr.includes(i - 1)) {
                    // sumamos 1 a los asientos laterales
                    laterales++;
                }
            } else {
                // Si el asiento es impar, comprobamos si no está ocupado el asiento +1 (el de su derecha).
                if (!arr.includes(i + 1)) {
                    // sumamos 1 a los asientos laterales
                    laterales++;
                }
            }
            // Comprobamos si está ocupado el asiento de atrás (+2), siempre y cuando exista el asiento
            if (!arr.includes(i + 2) && (i <= asientos - 2)) {
                traseros++;
            }
        }
    }
    // Devolvemos las posibilidades
    var posibilidades = (laterales / 2) + traseros;
    return (posibilidades);
}
```